# How the Akatsuki members turned all "missing-nin's"?

Tags: naruto

I know why Itachi went rogue, and why he left the village and joined the organization, and I know from other questions and answers why and how the members arrived to the Akatsuki, but I'd like to know why did the Hidden Villages and the Five Great Nation let these kinds of shinobi's to be excluded from their homes, nations, and eventually life?

Just think about it, since almost every member of the Akatsuki once belonged somewhere, and you should be a fool to mistreat and let go of fighters like: Kisame, Kakuzu, Hidan, etc. All of them are powerful warriors, immortals, owning a chakra level like a tailed beast, prodigies of the century, possessors of Kinjutsu's, etc. How come that a Kage isn't able to understand the importance of these kinds of men, especially when "a nation is reflected by the military power it has" and let them go wild, resulting in their exile from their own native villages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Missing-nins are not shinobi that got exiled from home. That does not happen.

Missing-nins always are shinobi who went rouge and left their villages willingly.

No village would want a shinobi of theirs going away and possibly to some other village spilling all their secrets? Especially not very powerful shinobi who were probably high in the ranks in their respective villages.

Comment: but that still doesn't explain why the village let them to go away? I mean,the leave,because e.g they feel uncomfortable or they were screwed or mocked or I don't know...you're not leaving your home just because

Comment: @Rinneg4n Sasuke left because he wants to kill his brother. Just cause he can..

Comment: Think of it as "Run away from home" to the max :)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha :)))....that would fit:)))

Comment: @Rinneg4n what do you mean by "let them go away"? If a ninja plans on going rogue, its not like he goes to the kage and asks for his permission, nor can the kage plead him to stay. Obviously the ninja runs away from the villa, and then they are put in the list of missing nins. Normally Anbus are appointed to elliminate them. That is also depicted by the cut in there headband that shows that they are no longer a part of the village that they previously belonged to.

Answer (score 0):

-Pain and Konan aren't missing ninja(They were rebels that became leaders of Rain)

-Zetsu isn't a missing ninja either, he's a creature of made matter.

-Obito/Madara/Tobi aren't really missing ninja either, he's KIA (Kill in Action)
Sure all four of them are S-Rank and in the Bingo Book(I Assume)

-Deidara became a missing ninja because he stole a kinjutsu(Forbiddin)

-Hidan ended up being blamed for a slaughter of a clan that had gone to the Valley of Hell, he believed that living there you were meant to kill(??) so he slaughtered his neighbours and joined the cult, Jashin.

-Itachi Uchiha(Really? Everyone knows how he became a missing ninja) He slaughtered his clan(Even if he was ordered/manipulated into doing it)

-Kakuzu failed in his mission of killing Hashirama Senju(The First Hokage) when he got back to his village he ended up being treated horribly (Kinda like what happened with Sakumo Hatake) he began to hate his village for being ungrateful for all he has done, he killed the elders, stole their hearts and fled with some kinjutsu.

-Kisame Hoshigaki has a lot of background, his comrades were selling information and he killed the, the Mizukage praised him for his loyalties to the village, he became disillusioned and in that time Madara(Obito) convinced him to work for him. Kisame became known as a missing ninja mainly became of all the assassinations he did, (The Daimyo being one of them)

-Sasori lost his parents young and when the puppets couldn't mimic the love he wanted/needed he became cold and aloof of human life.he begun to experiment about human puppets and guess just walked from the village.

-Orochimaru...human experiments, got busted, and fled.

-Juzo Biwa(No idea who he is, had to look him up)He is/was one of the Seven Swordsmen of the Mist. He is/was especially known for his brutality. It doesn't say anything on why he left, only that after the Third Great Shonbi War he became a missing ninja.

There hope that's a bit helpful.
Most of my research came from Fandom Wiki...really just google the character, click on the fandom wiki and oh...look at all that information.